# Julia: "Plot not defined" when attempting to add slider bars

Tags: julia

I am learning how to create plots with slider bars. Here is my code based off the first example of [this tutorial](https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/examples/layoutables/slider/index.html#slider)

```
using Plots
gr()
using GLMakie

function plotLaneEmden(log_delta_xi=-4, n=3)
  fig = Figure()
  
  ax = Axis(fig[1, 1])
  
  sl_x = Slider(fig[2, 1], range = 0:0.01:4.99, startvalue = 3)
  sl_y = Slider(fig[1, 2], range = -6:0.01:0.1, horizontal = false, startvalue = -2)
  
  point = lift(sl_x.value, sl_y.value) do n, log_delta_xi
      Point2f(n, log_delta_xi)
  end
  
  plot(n,  1 .- log_delta_xi.^2/6,  linecolor = :green, label="n = $n")
  
  xlabel!("ξ")
  ylabel!("θ")
end

plotLaneEmden()
```

When I run this, it gives `UndefVarError: plot not defined`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you add the plotting library e.g. `using Plots` at the beginning?

Comment: @AndreWildberg I forgot to add that. See edited code. Now my error is `UndefVarError: Slider not defined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to mix and match Plots.jl and Makie.jl. Specifically, the example from your link is entirely for Makie (specifically, with the GLMakie backend), while the the `plot` function you are trying to add uses syntax specific to the Plots.jl version of `plot` (specifically including `linecolor` and `label` keyword arguments).

Plots.jl and Makie.jl are two separate and unrelated plotting libraries, so you have to pick one and stick with it. Since both libraries export some of the same function names, using both at once will lead to ambiguity and `UndefVarError`s if not disambiguated.

The other potential problem is that it looks like you are trying to make a line plot with only a single x and y value (`n` and `log_delta_xi` are both single numbers in your code as written). If that's what you want, you'll need a scatter plot instead of a line plot; and if that's not what you want you'll need to make those variables vectors instead somehow.

Depending on what exactly you want, you might try something more along the lines of (in a new session, `using` only Makie and not Plots):

```
using GLMakie

function plotLaneEmden(log_delta_xi=-4, n=3)
  fig = Figure()
  
  ax = Axis(fig[1, 1], xlabel="ξ", ylabel="θ")
  
  sl_x = Slider(fig[2, 1], range = 0:0.01:4.99, startvalue = n)
  sl_y = Slider(fig[1, 2], range = -6:0.01:0.1, horizontal = false, startvalue = log_delta_xi)
  
  point = lift(sl_x.value, sl_y.value) do n, log_delta_xi
      Point2f(n, 1 - log_delta_xi^2/6)
  end
  
  sca = scatter!(point,  color = :green, markersize = 20)
  
  axislegend(ax, [sca], ["n = $n"])  
  fig
end

plotLaneEmden()
```

Or, below, a simple example for interactively plotting a line rather than a point:

```
using GLMakie

function quadraticsliders(x=-5:0.01:5)
  fig = Figure()

  ax = Axis(fig[1, 1], xlabel="X", ylabel="Y")

  sl_a = Slider(fig[2, 1], range = -3:0.01:3, startvalue = 0.)
  sl_b = Slider(fig[1, 2], range = -3:0.01:3, horizontal = false, startvalue = 0.)

  points = lift(sl_a.value, sl_b.value) do a, b
      Point2f.(x, a.*x.^2 .+ b.*x)
  end

  l = lines!(points, color = :blue)

  onany((a,b)->axislegend(ax, [l], ["$(a)x² + $(b)x"]), sl_a.value, sl_b.value)

  limits!(ax, minimum(x), maximum(x), -10, 10)

  fig
end

quadraticsliders()
```

[image: Makie.jl sliders for a quadratic equation]

ETA: A couple examples closer to what you might be looking for

Comment: AH, I guess I did not create the minimally reproducible example well. Does `Plots.jl` allow you to add sliders? Where can I find a tutorial?

Comment: Unfortunately not in Plots.jl by itself -- though I believe you can do it specifically in the context of a Plots.jl plot in a Pluto notebook: https://andreaskroepelin.de/blog/plutoslides/

Comment: Makie.jl can be a bit more complicated, but is also probably the most powerful plotting package in Julia

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a couple examples that might help on the Makie side